# Unable to store non-characters text in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I am trying sentiment analysis where I have data like

- *source_text*-> **@LiesbethHBC I have a good feeling actually ðŸ™ˆ its not that long, it's pretty soon!\nAw you deserve these tickets
  then!  ðŸ’–**
- *result_value*-> **Sentiment(polarity=0.0, subjectivity=0.0)**

I want to store this key value pair in a python dictionary.

I tried creating one as:

```
dict={}

dict[source_text].append(result_value)
```

but I get `KeyError` 
Is there a way to store such text(just not characters) in a dictionary?

Comment: dict[key] = item is the syntax you're looking for

Comment: And also don't use `dict` as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with "non-character text" (which doesn't mean anything actually), the only requirement for an object to be usable as a dict key is that it's hashable, and there's absolutely no restriction on what you can use as value.

Your problem quite simply comes from the fact that you're trying to get the value for an inexistant key (that's what `KeyError` means : the key you ask for does not exist in the dict).

Here :

```
mydict = {}
```

at this point, `mydict` is empty so just any item access will raise a `KeyError`

then you're doing this:

```
dict[source_text].append(result_value)
```

which is basically:

```
something = mydict[source_text] # get value for key `source_text`
something.append(result_value)
```

Since your dict is empty, the first line WILL obviously raise a `KeyError`.

If you want to store one unique `result_value` for each `source_text` value then the proper syntax is:

```
mydict[source_text] = result_value
```

If you want to store a list of `result_value` for each `source_text` value then you have to either explicitely test if the key is set, if not set it with an empty list, then append to this list:

```
if source_text not in mydict:
    mydict[source_text] = []
mydict[source_text].append(result_value)
```

or just use a `DefaultDict` instead:

```
from collections import DefaultDict
mydict = DefaultDict(list)
# DefaultDict will automagically create the key with an empty list
# as value if the key is missing
mydict[source_text].append(result_value)
```

Now I strongly suggest that you invest some time in properly learning Python (hint: there's a quite decent tutorial in the official documentation) if you have to use it, this will save on everyone's time.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @SushmitaMitkar glad if I could help  - and feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you tried to pull out the key `@LiesbethHBC I have a good feeling actually ðŸ™ˆ its not that long, it's pretty soon!\nAw you deserve these tickets then! ðŸ’–` in the dictionary which in this case is non-existent, Python gave you a `KeyError` meaning that the key didn't exist in the dictionary. A simple way to solve this is by initially checking whether you have that particular key in the dictionary, if yes, do whatever you wanna do with it, else create that key first.

By the way, avoid using `dict` (dictionary datatype) or any other datatypes as a variable name.

This is what you should actually do:

```
dictionary = {}  # Since, 'dict' is the dictionary data-type in Python

if (source_text in dictionary):
    # If the key exists...
    dictionary[source_text].append(result_value)

else:
    # If the key does not exist...
    dictionary[source_text] = []
```

This should help...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using '.update' method?

```
dict = {}
dict.update({'First':'Test'})
dict.update({'Lets Get':'Real'})
print (dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Testing': 'Dictionaries', 'Lets Get': 'Real'}
```

EDIT:
Or even:

```
dict = {}
dict.update({'Polarity':0.91})
dict.update({'Subjectivity':0.73})
print (dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Polarity': 0.8, 'Subjectivity': 0.73}
```

Comment: The canonical way to set a key in a dict is `mydict[key] = value`. `dict.update()` is only useful when you want to set multiple keys at once so doing two consecutive `update()` calls each with a single key:value pair is a complete WTF. As a side note if your keys are valid python identifiers you don't have to build another dict, you can just use `mydict.update(key1=val1, key2=val2)`.  But a none of this answers the OP's problem in anyway - he gets a `KeyError` for trying to get value for a key that is not set yet.